# What this error means for the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
x = ["slithy",[7,10,12],2,"tove",1]    
x[0][:3] = 'fea'
print(x)
```

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: it is w or x the variable name?

Comment: It is x. I have changed it.

Comment: strings are not mutable. You are trying to change `slithy`. You need to create a new string:  `x[0] = 'fea' + x[0][3:]`

Comment: Okay understood Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to modify the 0th element of the list, which is a string.

You would see the same error with this code

```
s = "slithy"
s[:3] = 'fea'
```

The reason for the error is that strings are immutable in Python and as such cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings are immutable. If your expected result is x = ["slifea",.....], this code is wrong and returns that error.